# How can I have bixby repeat an action but forget previous inputs?

Tags: bixby

I am working on a capsule that accepts an address and a zip code and will estimate the value of a property. At the results view, I would like to add a conversation driver to see if the user would want to get an estimate of another property. I would want to train an utterance to initiate the same action but also cause Bixby to forget the address and zip from the previous action.

From the testing i've done, it looks like continuations will hold on to values from the previous action. Is there a way to cause a continuation to forget those values? Or is there another way to accomplish this sort of action-repeat?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to look into the `transient` feature ([documentation link](https://bixbydevelopers.com/dev/docs/reference/type/structure.features.transient)) that you can define for concepts (zipcode, address, etc.).

Concepts marked `transient` will not be preserved in context and should provide you with what you need.